# Rails связь между двумя моделями

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Есть две модели Uploads и Products

```
class Products < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :upload
  attr_accessible :article, :cost, :id_category, :name, :quantity
end

class Upload < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :products
  attr_accessible :upload
  has_attached_file :upload, :path => ":rails_root/public/images/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  def to_jq_upload
    {
      "name" => read_attribute(:upload_file_name),
      "size" => read_attribute(:upload_file_size),
      "url" => upload.url(:original),
      "delete_url" => upload_path(self),
      "delete_type" => "DELETE" 
    }
  end

end
```

Как связать эти две модели между собой, что бы можно было через Products (id = 1) достать все изображения из Uploads ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне немного непонятны ваши намерения, так как вы объявляете "has one" и "belongs to", что предполагает связь "один-к-одному", но в вопросе хотите достать "все изображения для product (id = 1)". Тем не менее попробую ответить вам, возможно это что-то для вас прояснит:

Вам нужно более внимательно погуглить "Rails ассоциации" и почитать про отношения "has one - belongs to", а я отвечу своими словами:

Вот правильная расстановка ассоциаций для ваших моделей (я исключил остальные ваши строки для читабельности):

```
class Products < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :upload
end

class Upload < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
end
```

То есть смысл тут такой, что "Upload принадлежит продукту, а Product имеет один Upload", а не наоборот.

Предлагаю для иллюстрации изучить скрипт (он ниже), который я сделал основе [How to write an awesome Active Record bug report](http://www.jonathanleighton.com/articles/2011/awesome-active-record-bug-reports/) (это скрипт, который весь цивилизованный мир, в том числе ребята из Rails core, использует для моделирования простейших тестовых ситуаций, возникающих при работе с ActiveRecord).

Я изменил его немного для того, чтобы изобразить ваш случай. Вам нужно положить какую-нибудь картинку с именем image.jpg и этот скрипт в одну папку и убедиться в том, что у вас есть установленные гемы rails и paperclip

```
gem install rails
gem install paperclip
```

Ниже приведён сам скрипт, сохраните его как script.rb и запустите из директории, в которой лежат скрипт и картинка:

```
ruby script.rb
```

Сам скрипт:

```
gem 'rails', '>=3.1.0'
gem 'paperclip'

require 'active_record'
require 'paperclip'

# Print out what version we're running
puts "Active Record #{ActiveRecord::VERSION::STRING}"

# Connect to an in-memory sqlite3 database (more on this in a moment)
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  :adapter  => 'sqlite3',
  :database => ':memory:'
)

# Create the minimal database schema necessary to reproduce the bug
ActiveRecord::Schema.define do
  create_table :products, :force => true do |t|
  end

  create_table :uploads, :force => true do |t|
    t.belongs_to :product

    t.string :upload_file_name
    t.integer :upload_file_size
    t.string :upload_content_type
    t.datetime :upload_updated_at
  end
end

class ActiveRecord::Base
  # Это описано на https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/:
  # У нас нет полных Rails, поэтому мы подключаем Paperclip вручную
  include Paperclip::Glue
end

# Create the minimal set of models to reproduce the bug
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :upload
end

class Upload < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product

  has_attached_file :upload, :path => ":id/:style/:basename.:extension"
end

# Create some test data
#
# If you're demonstrating an exception, then this is probably not necessary,
# but if your bug is to do with the wrong data being returned from the database,
# then you'll probably need some test data to show that.

product = Product.create
upload = Upload.new

image = File.open("image.jpg")
puts image.inspect

upload.upload = image

product.upload = upload
product.save

product = Product.find(1)
puts product.inspect
puts product.upload.inspect
```

Если вдруг окажется, что для вас эта информация имеет слишком продвинутый уровень, задавайте вопросы.